# Can't get viewScoped bean from a SessionScoped bean

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean, view-scope, session-scope

i would need to get a viewScoped managed bean from a sessionScoped managed bean. I tried firstly using the *@ManagedProperty* annotation, but i discovered immediately the it does not work and i know why. Secondly i tried to use the following method:

```
Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();   
PulsantieraBean pulsantiera = (PulsantieraBean) viewMap.get("#{pulsantiera}");
```

but when i access in debug to the objects, pulsantiera is null and viewMap object contains only another viewScoped managed bean.
The **PulsantieraBean** class is declared in the following way:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = NomeBean.PULSANTIERA)
public class PulsantieraBean extends ControllerBaseBean implements Serializable {
```

whereas the class in which i do the request is declared as the following

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = NomeBean.IDF_TAB_IMPORTI)
public class IdfTabImportiBean extends ControllerBaseBean implements Serializable {
```

I do the request inside a method in which i am sure the viewScoped managed bean **PulsantieraBean** exists.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Marco

Comment: I'm not sure that viewMap accepts EL expression, did you tried with viewMap.get(NomeBean.PULSANTIERA)? Or use EL expression resolver : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29

Comment: Exactly why do you need to access a ViewScoped bean from a SessionScoped bean? That sounds like a design problem to be honest. More logically would be if it is the other way around - you access the session scoped bean from a view scoped bean.

Comment: Secondary: which version of JSF are you using exactly? There have been many bugs relating to the @ViewScoped annotation in the past (in Mojarra).

Comment: Actually I have not the absolute need to do this. It was an idea to do something that I have to do, but clearly I have other ways to do that. Above all, I tried to pass even the NomeBean.PULSANTIERA value because you are right, but I did not resolve the problem. The thing is that the viewMap object contains only another viewScoped managed bean, but not that I want.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Named(value = "controladorMB")
@SessionScoped
public class ControladorMB implements Serializable {}
```

call ControladorMB from ListadoFacturasMB

```
@Named(value = "listadoFacturasMB")
@SessionScoped
public class ListadoFacturasMB implements Serializable {

public void example() {
    try {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ValueExpression vex =ctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(ctx.getELContext(), "#{controladorMB}", ControladorMB.class);
        ControladorMB gMB = (ControladorMB) vex.getValue(ctx.getELContext());
       } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: buscarPersonalizado() " + e.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You showed an example that is not my case. I already know how to let two sessionScoped managed beans communicate each other